# Notepad++ Indent by Fold with XML Tag Auto Close

Tags: xml, plugins, autocomplete, notepad++, auto-indent

I'm looking for a way to code XML (mxml, specifically) in Notepad++ such that it follows the behavior of the "Indent by Fold" plugin - indentation after pressing 'enter' following an opening tag - but also includes automatic tag closing similar to what is provided by the "XML Tools" plugin.

The issue with enabling both at once is that I start with something like this:

```
<hello>|</hello>
```

(Note: the '|' character represents the cursor)

But after pressing 'Enter,' I get something that looks like this:

```
<hello>
   |</hello>
```

What I'm looking for is something that looks like this:

```
<hello>
   |
</hello>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** This question now exists on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/471596/notepad-indent-by-fold-with-xml-tag-auto-close)